# What the difference between a razor content page and a regular content page in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to ASP.NET so sorry if this is an obvious question. I did google it but I'm still confused.

So I created a master page in my ASP.Net project and I went to the website button at the top of visual studio to bring down the drop-down menu and clicked "add new item".

I went to add a content page and the only content page that shows up is "content page(razor)". This adds a page with a ".vbhtml" file extension. I'm trying to add a ".aspx" file with an attached vb page but it does not appear in the list.

If I right click the master page it gives me the option to add this type of content page but auto names it "default". so here's my question.

> Is there a way to add the regular content page while having the ability to name it before it is created?
>
> What's the difference between a razor content page and an asp content page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ASP.NET

- can be **Webform**

  - event driven coded
  - client side is aspx
  - contains `asp:controls`, html...
- **MVC** *(MVC 3, 4, 5, 6)*

  - MODEL - VIEW - CONTROLLER coded
  - client side is cshtml or vbhtml
  - contains `razor`, html...

If you want to create an ASP.NET webform, do not choose MVC, your project won't look the same and is not coded the same way.